# Is this function Riemann Integrable?

Tags: measure-theory

I've spent a lot of time in the past few months trying to solidify my background in measure theory, yet I find my brain still filled with a sea of contradictions and confusion.  Here is one, which I can hopefully get resolved.

Consider the sign function on $\mathbb{R}$.

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x\geq 0\\-1 &x < 0\end{cases}$$.

If I try to integrate this over $\mathbb{R}$ as an improper integral, I get
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx = \lim_{K\to\infty}\underbrace{\int_{-K}^{K}f(x)dx}_{=0} = 0$$

---

But using the Lebesgue integral, since $f^{+} = \chi_{[0,\infty)}$ and $f^{-} = \chi_{(\infty,0]}$, by definition

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f^{+}(x)dx + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f^{-}(x)dx = \infty - \infty$$
which is of course undefined.

---

So the question that arises, which integral am I using incorrectly? or is it both?

Comment: For it to be (improperly) Riemann integrable, you must be able to let the limits tend to $\pm\infty$ independently. It's neither Riemann nor  Lebesgue integrable, but it has a principal value.

Comment: Note that to use the Lebesgue integral, you need to have $\int |f| d\mu < \infty$ which fails here.

Comment: @DanielFischer:  thanks for clarifying that helps

Comment: @Jean: in case you read the comment that I just deleted.  I figured out why I was wrong.  thanks for your clarification as well